# Draw a bar chart one below the other Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe in pandas like this:

| State | Hispanic_freq | White_freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | freq1.1 | freq1.2 |
| Second | freq2.1 | freq2.2 |
| etc. | etc. | etc. |

I have a python code that wants to display graphs one below the other but not on the same graph. I will add that the columns Hispanic_freq, White_freq are float type.

```
for state in us_census_new.State:
  data = us_census_new[us_census_new['State'] == state]
  if data[['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq']].isnull().values.any():
    print(f'Missing value in {state}')
  else:
    values = data[['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq']].values.tolist()[0]
    plt.bar(['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq'], values)
    plt.show()
    plt.clf()
```

I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 87, in <module>
    plt.bar(['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq'], values)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2704, in bar
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1898, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2105, in bar
    left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 2105, in <listcomp>
    left = [left[i] - width[i] / 2. for i in xrange(len(left))]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

I check that my column dtypes, so:

```
print(us_census_new[['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq']].dtypes)
```

Give result:

```
Hispanic_freq    float64
White_freq       float64
dtype: object
```

I checked also that in my data sets that i have null values, so:

```
print(us_census_new[['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq']].isnull().sum())
```

Give:

```
Hispanic_freq    0
White_freq       0
dtype: int64
```

Do you have any other ideas why this might not be working?

Thanks :)

Comment: Which line exactly gives this error? Could you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76024777/edit) the full error trace to your post?

Comment: I add full error message :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your values array is not all floats. You may ha NaNs in there or it may be strings. check that out.

Also, if you want to have bar charts one below the other instead of on the same figure, you can either create a new figure for each loop - plt.figure() -
or create subplots

Comment: I add extra information about NaNs values and dtypes :)

Comment: try replace with this and tell me what happens:
values = data[['Hispanic_freq', 'White_freq']].astype(float).values.tolist()[0]